# Assigning one date field to another

Tags: java, date, datetime, gwt

I need to do some date manipulation without affecting the original date. If I do this:

```
Date tempDate = new Date();
tempDate = youthMember.getDob();
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(tempDate, 96);
```

Then both tempDate and youthMember.getDob() are incremented by 96 months. I have tried setValue(), setDate() and searching the net.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assigning a new Date just to throw it away on the next line, and naming a date 96 months in the future "tempDate" instead of something meaningful are both code smells to me.

Answer (score 3):

You have one date object pointing to the other, so they both return the same value.

```
Date tempDate = new Date(youthMember.getDob().getTime());
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(tempDate, 96);
```

Answer (score 1):

change tempDate initialization to this (it will create new instance and initialize it with same time as youthmember's dob)

```
Date tempDate = new Date(youthMember.getDob().getTime());
```

and remove this (because you are re referencing tempDate to youthMember's DOB)

```
tempDate = youthMember.getDob();
```